# IE10 - "Access denied" for frames

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

So, I did the research. If you're using frames in IE, it will give you the "access is denied". On their support website, they've indicated that if you're using frames, then you need to add your site in the trusted sites area (in internet options -> security, etc.) For the sake of it, I gave it a shot and added it to my browser's 'trusted' sites. Even after that, i'm getting the same error. Also, I looked at the other questions posted on stackoverflow before posting this question. Apparently, there are numerous reasons for getting this error. So, forgive me in advance for this long winded question post.

**My problem**:

I have a frame and the source of it is changed based on the hyperlinks that are within it. The page changes go well. Until I load a page that has a drop down box in it. when the drop down is changed the page is reloaded and I get a "access denied" error. Does anyone know a work around for this IE bug?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean iframes or frames?

Comment: You need to re-create refers to the `(i)frame`, when the location of the `(i)frame` changes.

Comment: @David Walters I meant to say iframes. The application functions fine in the beginning. AFter a couple of page refreshes, I get an "access denied" error. 

At ->Teemu my js file is inside the iframe that's being refreshed. So, i'm not sure why I would need to do that. It's a wierd problem.